# Eclipse CDT not fully parsing Eigen

Tags: c++, eclipse, parsing, eclipse-cdt, eigen

EDIT: This question was solved by creating a new workspace and there a new project. Probably there were some issues when porting the workspace from Eclipse Neon 2 to Eclipse Neon 3.

---

In Eclipse Neon 3 (on Windows), the following code is parsed without problems:

```
Array4f a;
Array4f b = (a + 2).square();
```

but

```
Array4f a;
Array4f b = (2 + a).square();
```

gives the error `Method 'square' could not be resolved`. Of course both compiles.

Where does the problem come from and is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: It works fine for me with Eigen 3.3. (I'm testing on Linux, but that shouldn't make a difference.) What Eigen version are you using? Also, what compiler and compiler version (that can matter because Eclipse parses the standard library headers that come with the compiler)?

Comment: @HighCommander4 strange! I also use Eigen 3.3, as compiler I use the GCC port to Windows "mingw-w64". To be exact, its the GCC version 6.2, mingw-w64 version "x86_64-6.2.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-rev1"

Comment: I've tried with GCC 6.2, and it still works for me. It might be worth giving the latest version of Eclipse, Neon.3, a try. I know some bugs that affected parsing Eigen headers were fixed between Neon and Neon.3, perhaps you are running into one of those.

Comment: @HighCommander4 I edited my question, I am actually using Neon 3 =(

Comment: @HighCommander4 I just set up a new workspace and there it worked! So there must be something with my workspace, since just setting up a new project did not help. Sorry for the trouble! I edited the question accordingly.